# KeyError in pygit upon deploying on divio.com

Tags: divio

Upon hitting the 'deploy' button on divio.com:

> ...
>   content = self[entry.id].read_raw() File
>   "/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygit2/repository.py", line
>   131, in **getitem** raise KeyError(key) KeyError:
>   354abadc2fab7b4d6c752f2660577d2ac3b5f247

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the divio support I was able to resolve this problem:

divio.com does not support "empty" folders in the repository.

Check if you have any unused folders that have been created by default and delete them (if you dont use them). Since I moved all the backend functionality into a `/backend` folder, I opted to just delete the automatically created folders:

```
mario@x1a2p32:~/Projects/lwl-djangocms-blog1$ git commit -m "delete empty folders"
[master e1144fa] delete empty folders
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 private/.empty
 delete mode 100644 static/.empty
 delete mode 100644 templates/.empty
```

This solved the problem and deployments now run fine.